# Add name to a list

Tags: c#, list

I need to add the player name to a list however it doesn't let me add the name to the list, i don't know why, I don't want to change it to a dictionary, since I have to swap players from a specific index so changing it into a dictionary is not a choice

When I write players.Add(player.Name); it says cannot convert from `string` to `SportsRosterManagement.Player`

```
class Team
{
    List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

    static Dictionary<string, Coach> Coaches = new Dictionary<string, Coach>();

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (name != "")
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
    }


    public Team()
    {
        name = "N.A";

    }
    public Team(string _name)
    {
        name = _name;


    }

    //use to add player to the players dictionary
    public void AddPlayer(Player player)
    {
       players.Add(player.Name);

    }
```

Comment: `List<Player> players = new List<Player>();` - that should be `List<string> players = new List<string>();` if you only want to store the `Name`

Comment: Now it says CS0030 Cannot convert type 'string' to 'SportsRosterManagement.Player' 
on both foreach loops

Comment: There are no `foreach` loops in the code you posted. Though it seems that you need to decide whether you only want to store the `Name` or the `Player` itself

Comment: Since the list is of type `List<Player>`, add it a player: `public void AddPlayer(Player player) { players.Add(player); }`

Answer (score 0):

Your list is of type `Player`, but you're trying to add the players' names, which is of type `string`.

Either change the list to a `List<string>`, or change the `AddPlayer` method to add the actual player instead of the name.

```
    public void AddPlayer(Player player)
    {
       players.Add(player);

    }
```